# How to set IDA to load my source file when analyzing my out file?

Tags: c++, gcc, ida

I have built my out file with gcc in Visual Studio.
And I can open this out file with IDA.
But I cannot find any way to let IDA load my source file of out file.
Because I need to check whether the compiler has inlined my function.
And I want IDA with source file could make my work easily.
Thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

IDA is a focused around reverse engineering, so unfortunately it does not support source files. You're better off using other, more appropriate, tools (Visual Studio, for example, can show you disassembly and source code aligned) or to use only the disassembly IDA provides.

As mentioned in the comments IDA does show debug symbols if they're included in the binary, but that's far from source code.

Comment: IDA can load debug information. You can build your executable with debug information, and that will help a bit. However it is probably better to feed your executable through objdump (it can provide disassembly mixed with source)

Comment: I had a test with Visual Studio, It seems that Visual Studio cannot analyze out file with source file. ( the windows format is supported by visual studio).